# If I open a file using vi editor and don't edit anything, will vi editor record it as "file edited" when doing ls -ltrh?

Tags: date-and-time

Question same as title. I'm investigating an issue and want to know this. Plus another issue I'm looking at is is it possible to modify a file without it being reflected in ls -ltrh command output or date -r command output? Someone has done it and I'm curious how. I know by using touch it is possible to modify a file's date. But I can't see touch command in history command(may be it evades reboot).

Comment: And you don't have access to a computer with Vim installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you do not make any changes, VIM exits without modifying the file. It does the same thing if you *do* modify the file but exit without writing (with ":q!").

As for whether it is possible to modify a file and *not* update the time stamp, it is not. You can, however, set the date to anything you want using `touch -t`. If you want to pretend that you did not modify a file, you can do this sequence:

```
cp myfile myfile.new
[edit myfile.new and save]
touch -r myfile myfile.new
mv myfile.new myfile
```

You now have an edited copy that looks like it was updated at the same time as the original.

Why you would want to do this, except to be deceitful, is a good question, but there are times when changing the modification time makes sense. In particular, using `touch -r` when dealing with `make` can sometimes be useful.

Comment: Someone has done that. I need to investigate.